Are my drop-in anchors fully set?
I'm installing 1/2" drop-in anchors into my very old (~1930's) concrete ceiling. The aggregate in that part of the ceiling is very dense (I think the rocks settled when it was poured) so the holes were very difficult to drill and I think the walls of the hole are mostly rock.
The instructions for the setting tool say to drive it in until its shoulder is flush with the anchor. I've been driving it with a 3-lb sledge and can't get the setting tool to go any deeper.
Is it possible for the anchor to be "fully set" or deformed enough to meet nominal pull-out strength without driving the setting tool all the way in? Or should I find a heavier-duty way of driving the setting tool

I think rather than trying to force the anchor, you should investigate why it's not going in fully.  Have you followed the manufacturer's directions, and is the hole the correct diameter and clear to the full depth?  It almost sounds like the hole isn't deep enough, or has some debris in it.  Those should go in pretty easily, so if you're not able to drive it in completely, then something is wrong.  Old concrete does get harder as it ages, so I'm not surprised it's difficult.  But with a hammer drill and suitable hammer drill masonry bit, it should be a pretty standard job.

Yeah, this sounds like an inadequate bore depth. You're going to scrape some material off the bore wall as you drive the anchor in, which reduces available space. Always go a half inch or so beyond hardware penetration.

The anchor itself is reaching the correct depth in the hole. Minimum embedment is 2" (flush) and I've got close to 3" on the shallowest hole so the anchor is sitting well past flush. I cleaned the holes out with compressed air before installing the anchors so I'm pretty confident that they're clean. If anything, I'd be worried that they're very slightly oversized.
So to be clear: the anchor is getting to the correct depth, the setting tool (for deforming the anchor) is not.

According to you description, it should be bedded properly. If the shoulder is on the ceiling surface and is not dropping back out under its own weight, it is set. You  can run a bolt in too, to draw or set the internal pin in, but the hard concrete will only let it do so much.
Since it is set in the ceiling I seriously doubt there is any debris in an upside down hole, so that will not be an issue. Most fasteners need an 1-1/4" minimum--this type is 2" minimum--a good depth for a lot of hold in concrete.
If the item being secured, not going to move, you are in good shape. I usually as a test hang from the fastener in a way so it proves to me it is working. The withdrawal force needed to pull that out should be astronomical with a 2" embedment.
The drive tool and hammer you used, in my opinion, did its job. There's no need to possibly cause damage to the insert by getting a bigger hammer.

Thanks Jack, I'm accepting this answer (and not just because it's the one I wanted). I was able to find a source that instructs to set until the tool is flush "or until it moves no further forward" which supports this.
I also installed an eye bolt with a nut putting as much preload as I could on the bolt and, when that hold, was able to proof test it and it worked so I'm considering this good enough.
